# copying files over multiple ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh

I have an awkward situation in which I need to link to a machine through multiple tunnels.  Details why below, but this command works for sshing in to `server2`:

```
ssh -A -t username1@portal1.host1.org ssh -A -t username1@server1.host1.org ssh -A -t username2@portal2.host2.org ssh -A username2@server2.host2.org
```

(for brevity, that command is now `$ssh_cmd`)
How can I copy files to/from that machine using a similar tunnel setup?  I have tried, for example:

```
rsync --rsh=ssh -e "$ssh_cmd" username2@server2.host2.org:filename .
```

which, even after removing the `-t`, fails because it doesn't give me an opportunity to enter my password:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

So how can I set up this tunneling copy command?

extra details:

- portal1 blocks proxy commands, which necessitates one extra of these jumps and prevents convenient `.ssh/config` hackery
- the failed authentications seem to have gotten me blocked at least once

EDIT: larsks suggested using key-based authentication, which worked to a point, then failed with:

```
debug1: Host 'server2.host2.org' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username2/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

which I don't understand; if it found the key why didn't it use it?

Comment: Can you just arrange to use key-based authentication instead of a password?

Comment: larsks: good idea; I tried that and it got further (one more server deep), but then failed.  See edit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, at least in part, that my `rsync` command was wrong.  The ssh command above should have excluded the last reference to the username/host, i.e.:

```
ssh -A -t username1@portal1.host1.org ssh -A -t username1@server1.host1.org ssh -A -t username2@portal2.host2.org ssh -A
```

instead of the command shown above.  This became evident in the debug output:

```
debug1: Sending command: ssh -Av username2@server2.host2.org -l username2 server2.host2.org rsync --server --sender -vvulogDtprCe.iLs . filename
bash: server2.host2.org: command not found
```

where it is redundantly specifying the server, such that the server name was being interpreted as a command remotely.

For the authentication failure, using key-based authentication solved the problem.

I also added `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to deal with the host key validation failure.